# How do I declare a Tuple that holds Delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, tuples, azure-durable-functions

I have a scenario where my methods can only accept 1 input parameter (*Azure Durable Function Activity Trigger*). To work around this, if I need multiple parameters, I stuff all my input values into a Tuple and then just pass the `Tuple` to the *activity trigger*.

I'm trying to create a Tuple that holds 3 items

1. Item1 = `Dictionary<string,string>`
2. Item2 = `Dictionary<string,string> MyFunction(T)`
3. Item3 = `T`

In short.

- `Item1` is a `Dictionary<string,string>`
- `Item2` is a Function that accepts a generic-typed object `T`, and outputs a `Dictionary<string,string>`
- `Item3` is a *generic-typed* object `T`

Id like to be able to execute `Item2`, using `Item3` as input.

The execution of `Item2` would produce a `Dictionary` that I will combine with `Item1`.

The issue I'm having is that the declaration syntax of a *delegate* doesn't really fit into a `Tuple` declaration syntax.

Here's how I attempted to type the Tuple with a delegate (which throws errors and does not work)

```
[FunctionName("MapOutputVariables")]
public Dictionary<string,string> MapOutputVariables<T>(
    [ActivityTrigger] Tuple<Dictionary<string, string>, delegate Dictionary<string,string> map(T x), T> input, 
    ILogger log)
    { ... }
```

How would I go about *correctly* declaring the delegate within the `Tuple`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

```
public Dictionary<string,string> MapOutputVariables<T>(
    (Dictionary<string, string> dict, Func<T,Dictionary<string,string>> callback, T somethingElse) input)
{
    input.callback?.Invoke(input.somethingElse);
    ...
}
```

I used a named [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0) and [`Func<T,TResult> Delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0), you could however stick closer to the original

```
public delegate Dictionary<string,string> MyDelegate<T>(T source);

public Dictionary<string,string> MapOutputVariables<T>(
    (Dictionary<string, string> dict, MyDelegate<T> callback, T somethingElse) input)
{
    input.callback?.Invoke(input.somethingElse);
    ...
}
```

or

```
public delegate Dictionary<string,string> MyDelegate<T>(T source);

public Dictionary<string,string> MapOutputVariables<T>(
    Tuple<Dictionary<string, string>, MyDelegate<T>,T> input)
{
    input.Item2?.Invoke(input.Item3);
    ...
}
```